# Give same result for "Home page" and "Homepage" in search table

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an search table and working perfectly. But i want that on writing "home page" like this and "Homepage" like this. In both the cases it shows the result for Home Page. Similary for "About us" and
"Contact us".

The code is given below.
Pls can anyone help me

```
#myInput {
    
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Search your product here">
<table id="myTable" align="center" border="5" width>
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Header 1 </th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><center>

<br><b>Home page</b></a></center></td>
    <td>   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><center>
    
    <br><b>About us</b></a></center></td>
    <td>
    
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><center>
    
    <br><b>Contact us</b></a></center></td>
    <td>
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex to replace the whitespace

```
filter = filter.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

EDIT for comment

```
filter = filter.replace(/\s/g,'')
txtValue = txtValue.replace(/\s/g, '')
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  tr[i].style.display = "";    
} else {
  tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: it works as when i search for "about us"(with space) and in results "aboutus"(without space) is available. But i want that if i search for "aboutus"(without space) then it shows the result "about us"(with space) which is in the results. Hope you understood. BTW Thank you

Comment: Try this line instead then
`if (txtValue.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, ''))indexOf(filter) > -1) {`

Comment: sorry, using this line it even stopped working. it didn't worked

Comment: I edited the answer, add the two lines of code before the IF statement and it should work now

Answer (score 1):

Remove all space using a regex pattern

```js
let str = "Hello World !";
let spacesRemoved = str.replace(/ /g, "");
console.log(spacesRemoved);
```